# ¿Cómo pintar una fila de un dataframe en python si una celda cumple una determinada condición?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

estoy trabajando con python 3.8 para sacar un .xlsx que contenga unas tablas. Uso la función pd.read_html(url) para leer las tablas que contenga una dirección web y luego:

```
table = pd.read_html(html)[0]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(table)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('salida.xlsx')
df1.to_excel(writer, 'Hoja1')
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Hoja1']
```

El punto es que si un registro de la tabla contiene el string 'Fallo', necesito que toda la fila correspondiente se pinte de rojo (añadirle background-color, quiero decir).

Por ejemplo, con esta función compruebo si está el string fallado y lo pinto de rojo:

```
def bgcolorCell(value, color):
worksheet.conditional_format(data, {'type': 'text',
                                    'criteria': 'containing',
                                    'value': value,
                                    'format': workbook.add_format({'bg_color': color})})
```

Pero lo que quiero es que no sólo esa celda tenga background, si no toda la fila correspondiente. ¿Alguien puede echarme una mano? Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes en principio usar el como tipo `"formula"` y proveer una fórmula Excel mediante la clave `"criteria"` que retorne `True` para toda celda en cuya fila exista una celda con el valor que buscas.

No se si es la mejor opción, mis conocimientos de Excel no son muy extensos, pero un `OR` es una opción, junto a indices con la columna absoluta, esto es importante.

```
import pandas as pd
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_rowcol_to_cell, xl_range



def row_bg_if_contain(
        df, workbook, worksheet, value, color,
        start_col=1, start_row=1,
        end_col=None, end_row=None):
    end_col = end_col + 1 if end_row is not None else len(df.columns)
    end_row = end_row + 1 if end_row is not None else len(df)
    cols = ", ".join((f'{xl_rowcol_to_cell(start_row, col, col_abs=True)}="{value}"' 
        for col in range(start_col, end_col + 1))
        )

    worksheet.conditional_format(
        f"{xl_range(start_row, start_col, end_row, end_col)}",
        {'type': 'formula',
          'criteria': f'OR({cols})',
          'format': workbook.add_format({'bg_color': color}),
          }
        )

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Foo": ("Aaaaa", "Bbbbb", "Ccccc", "Ddddd", "Fallo") ,
      "Bar":("Fallo", "Eeeee", "Fallo", "Fffff", "Ggggg")}
    )

with pd.ExcelWriter('salida.xlsx') as writer:
    df1.to_excel(writer, 'Hoja1')
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Hoja1']
    row_bg_if_contain(df1, workbook, worksheet, "Fallo", "red")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El formato de esta forma se mantiene de forma dinámica una vez creado el xlsx.

Otra posibilidad es usar los estilos de Pandas, el problema es que no mantiene el formato de forma dinámica sino que es estático, admás el soporte a Excel se considera experimental a día de hoy. La ventaja es que el formato se lo damos al propio DataFrame, por lo que en Jupyter Notebook o exportando a html el df lo podemos mostrar.

```
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Foo": ("Aaaa", "Bbbb", "Cccc", "Fallo") ,
      "Bar":("Fallo", "Deee", "Fallo", "Eeee")}
    )


def highlight_row_content(column, value):
    cont_val = column == value
    return ['background-color: red' if cont_val.any() else '' for v in cont_val]


(df1.style.apply(highlight_row_content, value="Fallo", axis=1)
    .to_excel('salida.xlsx', sheet_name='Hoja1')
    )
```

Comment: Me está sirviendo de mucho la verdad. Muchísimas gracias. Y ya para rematar, si en la celda además del string que quiero buscar aparece por ejemplo, la fecha, ya no tiene ese efecto. Se podría modificar el 'criteria' que has puesto con un 'containing' o algo así?